# Suppose a space is $T_0$ and $T_3$. is it necessary regular?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose a space is $T_0$ and $T_3$. is it necessary regular?

I don't think it is. A space is regular if it's both $T_1$ and $T_3$. However, a space is $T_0$ doesn't mean that it has to be $T_1$. but I can't find any good counter example for this.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/668234/8348).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't find a counterexample because $T_0$ and $T_3$ together imply $T_1$.

Let $x\neq y$. We need to find an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ that does not contain $y$. (Then the arbitrariness of the two points yields the result since we can change the roles of $x$ and $y$.)

$T_0$ guarantees (at least) one of

1. an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ with $y \notin V$, or
2. an open neighbourhood $W$ of $y$ with $x\notin W$.

In case 1., we're done, so let's assume 2. Then $F = X\setminus W$ is a closed set that is disjoint from $\{y\}$ and contains $x$. The $T_3$ axiom now says there are open $G_1, G_2$ with $y \in G_1$, $F \subset G_2$ and $G_1 \cap G_2 = \varnothing$. Then $G_2$ can serve as the required neighbourhood of $x$.